# Android WebView Upload File Name Not Set Correct

Tags: android, webview

I am using simple WebView to browse website which has upload file form with the form field  with the following code from stackovrflow:

```
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("ME", String.valueOf( requestCode));

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE) {
            if (uploadMessage == null)
                return;
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams
                    .parseResult(resultCode, intent));
            uploadMessage = null;
        }
    } else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return;
        // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside
        // Fragment
        // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an
        // Activity
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
        Log.i("ME", result.toString());
    } else
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                "Failed to Upload Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}



private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        // progressDialog.show();
        // progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        // activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);

        // progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress * 1000);

        progressBar.setProgress(progress);

        // if (progress == 100 && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        // progressDialog.dismiss();
        // }

        // activity.setTitle("Loading...");
        // activity.setProgress(progress * 100); // Make the bar disappear
        // after URL is loaded
        // Log.i("ME", ""+progress);

        // Return the app name after finish loading
        if (progress == 100) {
            // activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            loadingUrl = false;
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    // The undocumented magic method override
    // Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
    // For Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

    }

    // For Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }

    // For Android 4.1
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
            String acceptType, String capture) {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

    }

    // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView,
            ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
            WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        if (uploadMessage != null) {
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            uploadMessage = null;
        }

        uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

        Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            uploadMessage = null;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

On Android 5.1 it works fine. On Android 4.x.x and lower it uploads the file to the server normal but the file name is something like this:

```
image%3A9121
20098
24964
```

while the actual file names are something like:

```
image.jpg
image.png
image.jpeg
```

Why it changes the image file name to a number etc.

The onActivityResult show the result image url like this [using Log.i("ME", result.toString());]:

Content://com.android.providers.media.documents/documents/image%3A175458

The file is .jpg, does that means the %3A175458 refers to the ".jpg" in some character encoding?.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using the library [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser).

I just used the files FileUtils.java and LocalStorageProvider.java from that library and modified the onActivityResult with this code:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        Uri[] results = null;
        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[] { Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath) };
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[] { Uri.parse(dataString) };
                }
            }
        }
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;
            }
            Uri result = null;
            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    result = null;
                } else {
                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is
                    // null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();

                    Log.i("ME", "Uri = " + result.toString());
                    try {
                        // Get the file path from the URI
                        final String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, result);
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "File Selected: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        result = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Me", "File select error", e);
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: There is still a problem with that code. If the file name contains a URI-escaped character (like a space), the file upload shows a 0KB file. It is the bug : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=488443.